# Get area and perimeter of a UIBezierPath IOS

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uibezierpath, cgpath

I have a UIBezierPath:

```
    CGPathRef tapTargetPath = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(tracePath.CGPath, NULL, marginError, tracePath.lineCapStyle, tracePath.lineJoinStyle, tracePath.miterLimit);
    UIBezierPath *tracePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:tapTargetPath];
```

when it is touched in the method:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

I get a point. When i retrieve 2 points i want to get the segment(area or perimeter) of the UIBezierPath that i am touching, how can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

CGPathGetBoundingBox does not take into account the brush size and will cut the borders.

```
-(CGRect) getBiggerFrameFromPath:(CGPathRef) path{
    CGRect tmpFrame = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path);
    CGRect biggerFrame = CGRectMake(tmpFrame.origin.x-self.brushSize/2,
                                    tmpFrame.origin.y-self.brushSize/2,
                                    tmpFrame.size.width+self.brushSize,
                                    tmpFrame.size.height+self.brushSize);
    return biggerFrame;
}

-(void) refreshDisplayWithPath:(CGPathRef) path{
    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:[self getBiggerFrameFromPath:path]];
}
```

Comment: You should use `CGRectInset` to enlarge your initial rect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CGPathGetBoundingBox` to get the bounding box of the path, i.e., the smallest rectangle enclosing all points in the path:

```
CGRect pathBounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(tracePath.CGPath)
```